# downlaod issue with msys2 pacman

Tags: curl, proxy, msys, pacman-package-manager

I am trying to setup msys2 as mentioned [here](https://msys2.github.io/). When i do the step 5 to run the "pacman -Sy pacman", it reports that

```
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 403
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from downloads.sourceforge.net : The requested URL returned error: 403
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from www2.futureware.at : The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am running this under a network with authenticated proxy and i have already configured the proxy settings as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29783065/msys2-pacman-cant-update-packages-through-corporate-firewall) before running the "pacman" commands.

In the same shell, i ran the "pacman" with --debug option to get the URL of "mingw32.db" and tried to manually download that using "curl" as

```
 curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/i686/mingw32.db
```

This is able to download the file. So i assume my proxy setup is fine in the msys2 shell.

I am not sure why "pacman" is not able to download the file by itself as it internally uses "curl".

Any hints on what is wrong here?

Comment: Seems to be an intermittent issue with `mingw32.db` repos. It happens to me sometimes but the next day it works OK.

Comment: @ropata, thanks, atleast you are lucky

Comment: @user1767316 You say you want to make `pacman-game` a synonym for `pacman`, but this post has nothing to do with the game?! It's about the package manager with the same name.

Comment: @user1767316 exactly but I need to suggest a change to the pacman tag because it is often used for subjects related to pacman package manager and I need points linked to the pacman tag to do the suggestion ... but I only asked and answered questions about the pacman package manager ... I stoppped this attempt and put the right pacman-package-manager tag

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ... do not know yet if it gives a point, I stopped my attempts to get it this way anyway

Comment: @user1767316 Ah, now I get what you were trying to do. Ok.

Answer (score 3):

In the ***/etc/pacman.conf*** file, uncomment either line 18 or 19, to use either *curl* or *wget*:

```
XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
```

exit and restart the shell. The repos should be accessible now.

([Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=84619))

Comment: did that  - changed it to `/c/Windows/System32/curl` has no effect - `which curl` still returns `/usr/bin/curl` despite calling `/c/Windows/System32/curl --trace '/dev/stdout' http://www.google.com` working correctly 
And putting an alias in my .bashrc for that is a really sad solution (for this MSYS2 bug)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. The `mys2` curl package didn't work, but the `mingw` version did.

```
XferCommand = /mingw64/bin/curl -L -C - -f -o %o %u
```